# Why is Apache Livy session showing Application id NULL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-standalone, livy

I've implemented a fully functional Spark 2.1.1 Standalone cluster, where I **POST** job batches via the `curl` command using Apache Livy 0.4. When consulting the Spark WEB UI I see my job along with its application id (something like this: `app-20170803115145-0100`), with application name, cores, time, state, etc. But when consulting the Livy WEB UI (http://localhost:8998 by default), I see the following structure:

```
| Batch Id | Application Id | State   |
| -------- | -------------- | ------- |
| 219      | null           | success |
| 220      | null           | running |
```

And if I **GET** the state of all the batches I obtain the following result:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "total": 17,
  "sessions": [
    {
      "id": 219,
      "state": "success",
      "appId": null,
      "appInfo": {
        "driverLogUrl": null,
        "sparkUiUrl": null
      },
      "log": ["* APPLICATION OUTPUT"]
    },
    {
      "id": 220,
      "state": "running",
      "appId": null,
      "appInfo": {
        "driverLogUrl": null,
        "sparkUiUrl": null
      },
      "log": ["* APPLICATION OUTPUT"]
    },       
  ]
}
```

which is obviously correct, but I always see the null value in the **appId** field, also the **driverLogUrl** and the **sparkUiUrl**.

Is this field suppose to show the same application id that I see in the Spark WEB UI ? If so, how can I configure this or it has to be automatic ? Don't know if I'm missing some configuration line on the livy.conf or livy-env.sh file, because I can't find any example nor documentation regarding this.

This is my livy.conf file:

```
livy.server.host = IP_ADDRESS
livy.server.port = 8998
livy.spark.master = spark://MASTER_IP_ADDRESS:PORT
livy.spark.deploy-mode = cluster
livy.ui.enabled = true
```

This is the livy-env.sh file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java8/jdk1.8.0_91
export SPARK_HOME=~/sparkFiles/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=${SPARK_HOME}/conf
export LIVY_LOG_DIR=~/LivyRestServer/logs
```

**Please let me know if you need some more information.**

---

**UPDATE**
For those who has had the same issue.
Using the Standalone cluster manager unfortunately I couldn't fixed, but then I had the necessity to change it to YARN to better manage pools and queues, and that magically fix the issue, I was able to see all that information. Don't know why the standalone manager can't push the applicationId to Livy, but YARN does, so, it just fixed by itself, I didn't change anything in the Livy conf. files either.

Comment: did you found a solution to your issue?

Comment: Using the Standalone cluster manager unfortunately no, but then I had the necessity to change it to YARN to better manage pools and queues, and that magically fix the issue, I was able to see all that information. Don't know why the standalone manager can't push the applicationId to Livy, but YARN does, so, it just fixed by itself, I didn't change anything in the Livy conf. files either.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

[image: livy.conf]

`livy.spark.master` default is local mode,need set yarn mode;

Maybe it’s a livy bug,From a design perspective, it should also be obtained in local mode.
It may also be livy in the future only for the yarn mode.