# Apache Livy session showing Application id NULL

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, livy

Whenever I try to fetch the status of the livy application which ran on a GCP Dataproc cluster, It always returned me null value, irrespective what I changed in the livy.conf, This is bugging me,

I tried the same solution but no luck,
[Why is Apache Livy session showing Application id NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489852/why-is-apache-livy-session-showing-application-id-null)

My livy.conf file and I am using 0.8.0 version

```
livy.spark.master = yarn
livy.spark.deploy-mode = cluster
livy.server.session.timeout=1h
livy.environment production
livy.superusers dataproc,livy
livy.impersonation.enabled true
livy.server.yarn.app-lookup-timeout = 600s
livy.server.yarn.app-leakage.check_timeout = 600s
livy.server.yarn.app-leakage.check_interval = 600s
livy.server.yarn.app-leakage.check-timeout = 600s
livy.server.yarn.app-leakage.check-interval = 600s
livy.server.csrf-protection.enabled false
livy.spark.scala-version=2.12
```

Output what I am getting in Jupyter notebook

[image]

Can any livy expert who was able to view applications details in their livy setup assist me ?

Comment: Can you add the details of your Livy setup? version, how it is installed.

Comment: Livy version. --> 0.8.0. Using the livy zip file from their official website

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set a value for `livy.spark.master`

The default value is local mode, you need to set it to the resource manager you're using (yarn for exemple)

Comment: I tried with livy.spark.master = yarn still no luck